# What to deduct first from the discount? Is it the percentage or amount?

Tags: accounting, billing, deduction, discount, discounting

How to calculate a discount which have both deductions using Percentage and Amount at the same time.

***For e.g. Total Amount is 60,000 where I want 10% and 1,500 Discount. So if we deduct the 1,500 from 60,000 first we get the answer 52,650 and if we deduct the percent first then we get the amount 52,500.***

I'm really confused what to use first to get a legit result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no universal answer. It depends on the rules and policies of the entity that is offering the discounts.

Typically, in a retail setting, if a seller allows combining dollar-off coupons with percent-off coupons, the dollar-off will be applied first, because this is to the seller's advantage.

On the other hand, if the dollar-off discount is in the form of a cash-equivalent like a gift card, the buyer may be able to use it as a *method of payment* toward the percent-off price, meaning the percent-off is effectively applied first.